# Samsung tabe 2 default browser is not taking padding in select option drop down

Tags: html, css

In Samsung default browser(Internet) is not taking padding

I have tried

```
<select>
    <option>List 1</option>
    <option>List 1</option>
    <option>List 1</option>
</select>
```

I am applying the following CSS

```
select {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean Samsung Galaxy Note 1 ? Android version ?

Comment: No i have Samsung tab 2

Comment: The default browser for all androids is "WebKit based" meaning it is very related to `Google Chrome` and `Apple Safari`.

Comment: The `select` might be treated as `inline` either by default due to the browsers defaults or due to your other CSS code (such as reset stylesheets). Elements in inline mode will only have lateral padding (left-right) not vertical padding. Try setting the `select` to `display:block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution

```
select {-webkit-appearance: none;}
```